# IDEA yml format doesn't highlight

Tags: intellij-idea, yaml

IDEA doesn't highlight [yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvQT4.png) and doesn't validate it. But if specify the [yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2rEk.png) format, then it's fine.

How is it configured?

Comment: Please check file associations in "Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types"

Comment: @y.bedrov Thanks! I set the required formats.